# Left vs. left from

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I was under the impression that “left” and “left from” have very different meanings – for example, we can say:

**“The car left the garage an hour ago”**

Or

**“A pile of rubble is all that’s left from the garage after the bombing”,**

However, it is **incorrect** to say:

**“The car left from the garage”.**

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying that *the car left from the garage*. Adding the preposition is not something we would normally do, but it's fine to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using "left from" (in the sense you object to). It isn't usual, except in the case where you are specifying more precisely where the journey started, for example:

> He left Bradford this morning. Oh, which station did he leave from?

Comment: But I still can say “all that’s left from the garage after the bombing” or is it better to say “left of the garage”?

Comment: Yes, you can say either of those.

Comment: Forster Square, I bet. In a Class 333.

Comment: Could someone please decrypt the cyphertext above?

Comment: Oh, I partially get it! You must be referring to the Bradford Forster Square railway station which was demolished and rebuilt fairly recently. But wasn't the result satisfactory?

Comment: @Zak: a temporary station was built in 1992 while they rebuilt the main station with a new shopping centre. The temporary station is still there. (This is off topic).

Comment: Than I’m afraid I fail to grasp the point of this joke…

Comment: We'd have to ask @MichaelHarvey, but I don't think it is a joke. I think he's just showing off local knowledge.

Comment: it's a joke; I am a British railfan; I gambled that Colin would know what a Class 333 train is.

Comment: Actually, @MichaelHarvey, I'm that strangest of creatures, a railway enthusiast who has no interest in trains.

Comment: I'm not just interested in trains (i.e. the rolling stock) but also the infrastructure, the history, the culture, economics and politics. Do you mean you wouldn't get a little lump in your throat if you saw 4472 (I still call her that) start 15 coaches on a greasy rail, or in full flight?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: correct.